# Why does the compiler place DCUs that do not belong to the current package in its unit output directory?

Tags: delphi, build, package, delphi-10.1-berlin

I created two packages, `P1.dproj` and `P2.dproj`.

I put two empty units into the packages, so that `P1` contains `Unit1.pas` and `P2` contains `Unit2.pas`.

I edited the unit output directory to `.\P1\$(Platform)\$(Config)` and `.\P2\$(Platform)\$(Config)` in the respective packages.

I added P1 as a reference to the P2 project, so that P2 depends on P1.

The project files are stored in the same folder.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
  Root\
    Source\
      P1\
        Unit1.pas
      P2\
        Unit2.pas
    Packages\
      P1.dpk
      P1.dproj
      P2.dpk
      P2.dproj
      P1\
        Win32\
          Debug\
      P2\
        Win32\
          Debug\
```

Before I added the dependency P1 was outputting a `Packages\P1\Win32\Debug\Unit1.dcu` and P2 was outputting a `Packages\P21\Win32\Debug\Unit2.dcu`.

Nothing unexpected.

After I added the dependency when I just build P2 the IDE automatically compiles P1 as well, but the `Unit1.dcu` file is now outputted into the `Packages\P2\Win32\Debug\Unit1.dcu`.

Why is that?

The `Unit1.dcu` file is not in the `Contains` list of `P2.droj` nor is it listed in any library path or browsing path (neither Delphi global nor project local).

Why does the compiler put stuff into the unit output directory of the current project that it does not even have access to the source directory of?

When I move the P1 dpk/dproj files away into some sub folder and restart the IDE it will correctly complain that it can not find the `P1.dcp` file and not start to compile anything from P1.

I had noticed this behaviour in a bigger, more complicated setup and it was driving me crazy ...

Comment: I can't duplicate this with Berlin; added a new project to the group, added a dependency. Compiled, both compiled and for both projects the DCUs ended up in the correct place.

Comment: Specifically the projects have to be `packages` and you have to create a reference from one package to the other (not just a build depedency in the project group).

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff - You can control this using the "Build Control" setting in P1's Project Options.   The default value is "Rebuild as Needed".  Change it to "Explicit rebuild" and it will prevent this behavior. (just updated the answer for this)

Comment: Interesting thought! I only ever came in contact with that setting in context of compiler errors such as "E2225 Never-build package 'Package A' must be recompiled".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing this because the source files for both packages are in the same directory **and** P1 is set for "Rebuild as needed" in it's Project options.

Think about a simple project Proj1 that contains and uses a unit U1.  U1 uses U2 which is **not** included in Proj1. The compiler must be able to see U2.dcu; probably in the current Library path or some other common "lib" directory.  When Proj1 is compiled, U1.dcu goes into Proj1's unit output directory but U2.dcu is simply "used" from wherever it currently lives and does not appear in Proj1's unit output directory.

Now, suppose you add the directory where U2.pas exists to Proj1's search path.  Now the compiler can see U2.pas, so it compiles it and places the resulting U2.dcu  into Proj1's unit output directory along with U1.dcu

It's the same thing here...P2 "requires" P1.  That is, when compiling P2, the compiler needs to see either P1.DCP or all of the source files for P1 (P1.dpk and unit1.pas in this case).

In your case, it can see P1.dpk because it's in the same directory, so it compiles it and places the resulting dcu's (unit1.dcu in this case) into P2's unit output directory.

You can prevent this behavior by setting **P1** to "Explicit Rebuild" in it's project options.  When building P2 or any package that "requires" P1, this tells the compiler "even though you can see P1's source, do not build it."

Comment: That all makes sense, except for the last paragraph. Why does the compiler not try to build P1 then, but instead opts to build U1? If Unit1.pas were in some include / lib / whatever environment directory I could see that it "makes sense" (actually I would prefer that the compiler would not just start compiling **anything** that is not part of the current project, but that is just my personal opinion), but this is going one step too far for me.

Comment: I guess I have to separate the project files into different directories then *sigh*.

Comment: In the bigger project group this actually led to units being compiled multiple times and eventually that led to the dreaded `compiled with a different version` error message.

Comment: >>>"...not try to build P1 then, but instead opts to build U1"....     it's not "opting" to build U1 instead of P1.   P2 "uses" P1; it's building P1 (and any units inside it) *because* it can see P1.dpk

Comment: "I guess I have to separate the project files into different directories"    --  Yes.

Comment: " it's not "opting" to build U1 instead of P1" ... but it *is*! The U1.dcu is then placed in both unit output directories.

Comment: It is building P1.  Because it can see P1.dpk.    U1 is *in* P1, so that's why the U1.dcu is emitted.    P1 is being compiled *in the context* of P2.  That's why unit1.dcu ends up in P2's dcu output directory.